# How to determine sign of 'y' for differential equation that involves x and y

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

For example:

Find the general solution of $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{-x}{y}$, given that $y(1) = 1$.

I don't understand/know the method to determine if $y$ is positive or negative for this differential equation? The result is $x^2 + y^2 = 0.5$, so solving for $y$ is an issue.

I was never introduced to the method when $\frac{dy}{dx}$ includes variables $x$ and $y$ so I'm completely stuck...

Thanks

Comment: First, its $x^2 + y^2 = 0.5$. secondly both the negative and the positive are possible solutions.

Comment: Look [here](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/differential-equations/first-order-differential-equations/homogeneous-equations/v/first-order-homegenous-equations)

Comment: The result can not be $x^2+y^2=1$ bacause initial point $(1, 1)$ doesn't belong this circle - the radius must be $\sqrt 2.$  As $y(x)=1>0$ at initial point (and thererefor in neiwborhood) it stay be positive.  Thus, the solution is the upper semicircle.

Comment: @Minz, thanks for the help. But for example, if we had dy/dx = y/x, given that y(1) = 1. We get y=x, but why don't we need to make the restriction y>0 to satisfy the initial condition like we did in the previous question above?

Comment: @adequace, Why dont - we do have such restriction, and the solution would occur  $y=x>0$ because we  must not get to the point $(0,0)$.